# Can I call Lock within two unrelated functions without one lock affecting the other?

Tags: google-apps-script, locking

If I have two unrelated functions in `Code.gs` (which each interact with a different Google Sheet), can I call `lock` within both functions without one call effecting the other?

For further context, the app, which has around 80 users within the same domain, is running as Me, however it is possible that:

- User A calls `myFunction_01()` at the same time as
- User B calls  `myFunction_02()`

In this scenario, will the locks operate independently?

Is the following implementation of `lock` acceptable?

```
function myFunction_01() {

var my_spreadsheet_01 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YYY");

var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();

try {
  lock.waitLock(30000); 
} catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 30 seconds.');
    var returnObjectCatchError = {};
    returnObjectCatchError['LockErrorFlag'] = "An exception occurred when waiting for lock"; 
    return returnObjectCatchError; 
}

// do things with my_spreadsheet_01 here

var return_object = {};

// apply all pending spreadsheet changes
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

//release lock
lock.releaseLock();

return return_object;

}

function myFunction_02() {

var my_spreadsheet_02 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ZZZ");

var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();

try {
  lock.waitLock(30000); 
} catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 30 seconds.');
    var returnObjectCatchError = {};
    returnObjectCatchError['LockErrorFlag'] = "An exception occurred when waiting for lock"; 
    return returnObjectCatchError; 
}

// do things with my_spreadsheet_02 here

var return_object = {};

// apply all pending spreadsheet changes
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

//release lock
lock.releaseLock();

return return_object;

}
```

Comment: The ultimate way to know for sure is to test it.  The two functions are opening two different spreadsheet files, `YYY` and `ZZZ` so there is no chance of one function interfering with the other spreadsheet.  If `myFunction_01` and `myFunction_02` were both opening the same spreadsheet, then there would be the chance for a conflict.  Your variable name is `active_spreadsheet` but then you are opening a spreadsheet by ID.  Is that the example that you wanted to give?  Even if function 1 and function 2 were called simultaneously, they will run at the same time and independently without a lock.

Comment: I thought perhaps that if `function_01` and `function_02` ran simultaneously and `lock` was run in `function_01` a fraction of a second before it ran in `function_02`, then it would not be available in `function_02`?  That line of thinking was based on this [possibly out of date answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19137603/1063287) that says "There is only one public lock and only one private lock".  So I am just after a definitive and up to date answer on whether you can have multiple instances of lock dispersed throughout multiple functions - and if not, what the official alternative is.